# Layout problem with KOMA-Script and dictums

Tags: koma-script, epigraphs

I have two problems when using dictums with KOMA-Script.

1. There is no space between the dictum and the following paragraph.
2. The first paragraph chapter starts with an indent.

I'm able to make it look right by writing `\bigskip\noindent` under each dictum, but how can I redefine `\dictum` so that this happens automatically?

###### Minimal working example

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\dictum{An epigraph is a short quotation or saying at the beginning of a book or chapter, intended to suggest its theme.}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eu efficitur purus, vitae mollis risus. Curabitur lorem elit, tempus sed mollis ac, luctus eget leo.
\end{document}
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the KOMA Script manual, it is recommended to use `\dictum` inside `\setchapterpreamble` for chapters. This takes care of the spurious indent. The manual also notes that "*you* are responsible for the spacing between the heading, preamble, and the
following text". You can easily write a convenient macro.

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcommand\setchapterdictum[1]{%
  \setchapterpreamble{%
    \dictum{#1}%
    \bigskip
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\setchapterdictum{An epigraph is a short quotation or saying at the beginning of a book or chapter, intended to suggest its theme.}
\chapter{Chapter Title}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eu efficitur purus, vitae mollis risus. Curabitur lorem elit, tempus sed mollis ac, luctus eget leo.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks a lot!